# Unity Admob Ads Showing in Editor but not in Xcode or published app

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob, cocoapods

I am working in Unity 2020.3.13f1.  Admob banner, interstitial, and rewarded ads work fine in the editor but do not show when I test in Xcode,  nor do they show when my app is live on the App store (Even after the 24 hours or however long they sometimes take to start showing).  However they work fine on Google Play.  As far as I know I have followed Google's Unity implementation guide exactly.  Is there something I could be messing up in the way of installing pods, or perhaps is there a framework I should manually link in Xcode that Unity does not automatically do for me?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is one possibility your live app id can't be approved for app yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of things that could be going on.

Are you manually integrating Admob or using a plugin? It's such a pain we eventually bought Easy Mobile Pro to do a lot of the integration for us.

Is your iOS app published in the app store? We had a similar issue but Admob ads won't show until your app is published in the app store.

Are you correctly handling Apples new App Transparency Tracking? [Admob Guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14) This includes adding the proper SDAdNetworkItems to your info.plist file and several other steps.

We also had some other plugins interferring like Nice Vibrations.

Try building a release build in Xcode and view the console. We were seeing this error message which has numberous potential causes.

```
AVAudioSession.mm:997:-[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  I have been using the plugin, and have tried several versions, not just the new 6.x ones.  The app is published in the store and the ads still won't show.  Perhaps it needs to be linked in admob?  I will try linking and see what happens.  In answer to you last question, the plugin automatically ads the SKAdnetwork items to the plist.  However I was unaware that ATT answers could prevent ads showing entirely.  Whether the ATT was set up or not, wouldn't the ads still show, just not link to the IDFA or whatever?

Comment: If someone asks not to track they’ll likely get fewer ads and lower paying ads. When we first launched we went a few days where almost no one who asked not to track saw ads but I would rule out all other issues via the Xcode console when you build and run on a test device to confirm you aren’t getting errors. Anything without that is just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

First, is your admob app linked to the playstore app? Which google admob package are you using on unity? (which version).

Versions 6.0.0 and 6.0.1 are encountering quite a few problems apparently, including the fact that the app id disappears after you put it on unity (basically if you close and open the project, the app ids disappear), so I advise you at the moment to use version 5.4.0 to get started.

Then another thing I wonder is if you are integrating google packages into xcode manually (by downloading Google Mobile Ads iOS from the internet and then adding all the various packages to the project manually), or if you are doing it automatically with cocoapods (which is the recommended way)

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I have used multiple plugins and was using cocoa pods.  It is published on the App Store but is not linked in Admob.  Does it need to be linked to show ads?  I have published apps on Google Play that have not been linked in Admob and have worked fine.  I just assumed it would be the same with IOS.  Would I have to wait 24 hours after linking like I have read in other places to see if the ads show or not?  Hopefully linking is the problem, as it is about the easiest fix I could hope for.

Comment: @pault8383  I have never seen ads on ios without connecting the app.
Wait 48 hours after the app is published and try to connect it. If you are successful, ok, otherwise go to this group: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk, open a conversation and type in the object "I can not connect the ios-admob app" and in the body enter the link of the app. In less than a day (sometimes a few hours) they reply telling you that they have solved it and that you are able to connect it. I didn't notice the waiting time from the app link. but i think in two days maximum the ads should be regular

Comment: I don't have the reputation to comment on the other post but I care. If the user denies the ATT denies the IDFA and therefore the ads will not be personalized based on the user's advertising data. This does not mean that the user sees fewer ads, or that they see less profitable ads. The amount of ads remains regular and the amount of money the ad pays is the same. What it affects is the number of clicks. Personalized ads are shown to increase interest and therefore clicks. Non-personalized ads will be less profitable not because they pay less, but because they are clicked less.